# How can I save the jointjs link exact positions?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, jointjs

I have an application which uses jointjs to connect several different cells to each other. After the user creates a workflow, they can then save the workflow. So far I have managed to save the current connections, but I cant seem to find any documentation that tells me how to save the particular link locations and vertices so I can restore the exact line positions that the user created.

Currently, when I restore a workflow, the links are recreated using manhattan routing, this the user loses their line structure.

I'd also like to note that I cannot just use the jointjs function 'toJSON' because I am saving the graph to XML.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have to use XML? JSON would seem to be a more natural choice for javascript and as you point out, it is supported by JointJS...

Comment: Yea unfortunately, because the server handles xml, it has to be done with xml. I wish it could be done with JSON. So far i've been able to retrieve the vectors of the lines by searching the dom. No idea how to apply those vectors to the lines however.

Comment: a bit hacky but could you embed the stringified JSON into the XML?

Comment: So i just checked, the jointjs native toJSON functions don't include the exact line positions. It only includes the target and source of the line, and the vectors for the arrow marker at the end of the line. So far the only way I've been able to get the line positions is like i stated above, from the dom. I don't like it either lol...

Comment: Actually I found a method that should do it. link.get("vertices") and link.set("vertices"). However link.get("vertices") returns undefined for me. Hmmm, I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Okay, another quick update, so get vertices only works if you've previously set the vertices. If you set the vertices, those vertices can no longer be changed, the line will only extend and transform around those set vertices. Now I'm thinking maybe the best way to fix that is implement an on change event listener for the cells. If the cell moves, remove the vertices array of the links attached to said cell.

Comment: When I recreate a diagram using the json the line positions are recreated exactly. Done using graph.fromJson function.